# When running expo build:android, I get 'expo build:android has been discontinued (January 4, 2023)' Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, build, expo

When running the command `expo build:android` I get an error that reads:

`expo build:android has been discontinued (January 4, 2023).`

I just installed my expo and it works fine on emulator. I am just not able to use this build command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`expo:build` was only supporting sdk 46 and lower.

**Try running these commands instead:**

`eas build:configure`

and then

`eas build -p android`

more info on this can be found [here](https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60) and [here](https://docs.expo.dev/archive/classic-updates/building-standalone-apps/).

Answer (score 5):

Expo's classic build service was replaced by EAS build.

The classic build service (run with `expo build` command) was designed in 2016 for how Expo apps worked back then: each app included all of the native modules in the Expo SDK and there was no way to fully customize the app’s native code. We needed a new build service to support building modern Expo apps with custom native code in the cloud - what's now EAS Build.

EAS Build has been available since late 2021, and classic builds were finally sunset in Jan 2023.

More context here: https://blog.expo.dev/classic-build-service-no-longer-supported-73c82b500f56

And more info on switching to EAS Build: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/

Comment: what !?? After years they force use to use only cloud build ?!? we in the free tier are actually waiting for >30 mins every time. Only firtst build is 'fast'.