# How to build .apk or .aab file in react native expo without sending it to the server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native

If we are building .apk or .aab file again and again, it is taking too much time to build. Please let me know the method with which we can build file locally.

I have already tried to build locally with this command

```
eas build:configure
```

and then

```
eas build -p android
```

However, still it is sending to the expo server, but I don't want that.

Comment: if you are using expo-cli you can use `expo build:android -t app-bundle` to build app bundle

Comment: `expo build:android -t apk` for apk

Comment: I have already tried this but getting this error:
expo build:android has been discontinued (January 4, 2023).

Comment: have tried  [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183247/when-running-expo-buildandroid-i-get-expo-buildandroid-has-been-discontinued)